# Java program slows down abruptly when indexing corpus for k-grams

Tags: java

I have a problem which is puzzling me. I'm indexing a corpus (17 000 files) of text files, and while doing this, I'm also storing all the k-grams (k-long parts of words) for each word in a `HashMap` to be used later:

```
public void insert( String token ) {
    //For example, car should result in "^c", "ca", "ar" and "r$" for a 2-gram index

        // Check if token has already been seen. if it has, all the
        // k-grams for it have already been added.
        if (term2id.get(token) != null) {
            return;
        }

    id2term.put(++lastTermID, token);
    term2id.put(token, lastTermID);

        // is word long enough? for example, "a" can be bigrammed and trigrammed but not four-grammed.
        // K must be <= token.length + 2. "ab". K must be <= 4
        List<KGramPostingsEntry> postings = null;
        if(K > token.length() + 2) {
            return;
        }else if(K == token.length() + 2) {
            // insert the one K-gram "^<String token>$" into index
            String kgram = "^"+token+"$";
            postings = index.get(kgram);
            SortedSet<String> kgrams = new TreeSet<String>();
            kgrams.add(kgram);
            term2KGrams.put(token, kgrams);
            if (postings == null) {
                KGramPostingsEntry newEntry = new KGramPostingsEntry(lastTermID);
                ArrayList<KGramPostingsEntry> newList = new ArrayList<KGramPostingsEntry>();
                newList.add(newEntry);
                index.put("^"+token+"$", newList);
            }
            // No need to do anything if the posting already exists, so no else clause. There is only one possible term in this case
            // Return since we are done
            return;
        }else {
            // We get here if there is more than one k-gram in our term
            // insert all k-grams in token into index
            int start = 0;
            int end = start+K;
            //add ^ and $ to token.
            String wrappedToken = "^"+token+"$";
            int noOfKGrams = wrappedToken.length() - end + 1; 
            // get K-Grams
            String kGram;
            int startCurr, endCurr;
            SortedSet<String> kgrams = new TreeSet<String>();

            for (int i=0; i<noOfKGrams; i++) {

                startCurr = start + i;
                endCurr = end + i;

                kGram = wrappedToken.substring(startCurr, endCurr);
                kgrams.add(kGram);

                postings = index.get(kGram);
            KGramPostingsEntry newEntry = new KGramPostingsEntry(lastTermID);
                // if this k-gram has been seen before
                if (postings != null) {
                    // Add this token to the existing postingsList.
                    // We can be sure that the list doesn't contain the token
                    // already, else we would previously have terminated the 
                    // execution of this function.
                    int lastTermInPostings = postings.get(postings.size()-1).tokenID;
                    if (lastTermID == lastTermInPostings) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    postings.add(newEntry);
                    index.put(kGram, postings);
                }
                // if this k-gram has not been seen before 
                else {
                    ArrayList<KGramPostingsEntry> newList = new ArrayList<KGramPostingsEntry>();
                    newList.add(newEntry);
                    index.put(kGram, newList);
                }
            }

            Clock c = Clock.systemDefaultZone();
            long timestart = c.millis();

            System.out.println(token);
            term2KGrams.put(token, kgrams);

            long timestop = c.millis();
            System.out.printf("time taken to put: %d\n", timestop-timestart);
            System.out.print("put ");
            System.out.println(kgrams);
            System.out.println();

        }

}
```

The insertion into the `HashMap` happens on the rows `term2KGrams.put(token, kgrams);` (There are 2 of them in the code snippet). When indexing, everything works fine until things suddenly, at 15 000 indexed files, go bad. Everything slows down immensely, and the program doesn't finish in a reasonable time, if at all.

To try to understand this problem, I've added some prints at the end of the function. This is the output they generate:

```
http://soccer.org
time taken to put: 0
put [.or, //s, /so, ://, ^ht, cce, cer, er., htt, occ, org, p:/, r.o, rg$, soc, tp:, ttp]

aysos
time taken to put: 0
put [^ay, ays, os$, sos, yso]

http://www.davisayso.org/contacts.htm
time taken to put: 0
put [.da, .ht, .or, //w, /co, /ww, ://, ^ht, act, avi, ays, con, cts, dav, g/c, htm, htt, isa, nta, o.o, ont, org, p:/, rg/, s.h, say, so., tac, tm$, tp:, ts., ttp, vis, w.d, ww., www, yso]

playsoccer
time taken to put: 0
put [^pl, ays, cce, cer, er$, lay, occ, pla, soc, yso]
```

This looks fine to me, the putting doesn't seem to be taking long time and the k-grams (in this case trigrams) are correct.

But one can see strange behaviour in the pace at which my computer is printing this information. In beginning, everything is printing at a super high speed. But at 15 000, that speed stops, and instead, my computer starts printing a few lines at a time, which of course means that indexing the other 2000 files of the corpus will take an eternity.

Another interesting thing I observed was when doing a keyboard interrupt (ctrl+c) after it had been printing erratically and slowly as described for a while. It gave me this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.newString(StringLatin1.java:549)sahandzarrinkoub@Sahands-MBP:~/Documents/Programming/Information Retrieval/lab3 2$ sh compile_all.sh
Note: ir/PersistentHashedIndex.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Does this mean I'm out of memory? Is that the issue? If so, that's surprising, because I've been storing quite a lot of things in memory before, such as a `HashMap` containing the document ID's of **every single** **word** in the corpus, a `HashMap` containing every single word where every single k-gram appears, etc.

Please let me know what you think and what I can do to fix this problem.

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError` means that you are out of memory, yes. You can control the heap memory with `java -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m ...` (this would set the heap size on a minimum of 2048 MB and a maximum of 4096 MB). you can find more information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html). But keep an eye of your actual memory: if your system starts swapping, a bigger heap memory will not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this, you must first understand that java does not allocate memory dynamically (or, at least, not indefinetly). The JVM is by default configured to start with a minimum heap size and a maximum heap size. When the maximum heap size would be exceeded through some allocation, you get a [`OutOfMemoryError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)

You can change the minimum and maximum heap size for your execution with the vm parameters `-Xms` and `-Xmx` respectively. An example for an execution with at least 2, but at most 4 GB would be

```
java -Xms2g -Xmx4g ...
```

You can find more options on the [man page for `java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html).

Before changing the heap memory, however, take a close look at your system resources, especially whether your system starts [swapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Terminology). If your system swaps, a larger heap size may let the program run longer, but with equally bad performance. The only thing possible then would be to optimize your program in order to use less memory or to upgrade the RAM of your machine.